# Laravel - Read .env.testing variables using env method

Tags: laravel, testing, environment-variables

I'm trying to retrieve environment variables inside into my `.env.testing` environment. But when i use the `env()` method in an Artisan command it shows
me the variables of my `.env` file.

There's some way to retrieve `.env.testing` variables using a simple function?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a simple solution:

```php
$env = '.env.testing';
$envRealpath = base_path() . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $env;

$envParsed = \Dotenv\Dotenv::parse(file_get_contents($envRealpath));
```

And it shows somenthing like this:

```php
dd($envParsed);

array:8 [
  "APP_ENV" => "testing"
  "APP_KEY" => "base64:UhZJnxghjYRyO/uZiKqMAmBvMa+vxentaxdnUiweRxg="       
  "DB_CONNECTION" => "mysql"
  "DB_HOST" => "127.0.0.1"
  "DB_PORT" => "3306"
  "DB_DATABASE" => "base_backend_laravel_testing"
  "DB_USERNAME" => "testing"
  "DB_PASSWORD" => "testing"
]
```